I have a question about Theorem5.3 in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry
Theorem5.3. Let $Y$ be a variety. Then the set Sing$Y$ of singular points of $Y$ is a proper closed subset of $Y$. 
Proof. First we show Sing$Y$ is a closed subset. It is sufficient to show for some open covering $Y 
= \cup Y_i$ of $Y$, that Sing$Y_i$ is closed for each $i$.
I think that Sing$Y$ is not necessarily closed even if Sing$Y_i$ is closed.
Because infinite sum of closed subset is not necessarily closed. I'd be thankful for pointing out what went wrong here.

A set is closed if and only if its intersection with each element of an open cover is closed in that element. This is a fact of topology he uses in the proof.

Thank you for your answer
